# Load html file at Page_Load or OnInit

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to load a html file "en_index.html" at Page_Load. But I get following errors:

**Errors:**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://example.org/langs.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://example.org/provider/mainstyle.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://example.org/css/ltrstyle.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://example.org/provider/main.js
```

**Default.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
          Response.WriteFile("en_index.html");
      }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {

   }
}
```

**en_index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>en_index</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Here comes project description." />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        currMode = "advanced"; lang = "en"; 
    </script>
    <script src="langs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="provider/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="provider/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/ltrstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

There are no problems with html file because it works fine when I run it individually. But not when I run Default.aspx. Any suggestion/ideas? How should I achieve it?

---

I have also tried following at page load:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("File1", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("langs.js"));
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("File2", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/provider/main.js"));
```

Comment: Right before the edit I think I saw you wrote that on localhost it's working and you got this problem only on remote server is that right?

Comment: Errors of type 500 are pretty generic but in this case I think it's clear - the server can not find the `.js` and `.css` files where you told him to look at. My suggestion is to try something like `Scripts.Render("~/provider/main.js")` or maybe even `Scripts.Render(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("provider/main.js"))` but those are only guesses.

Comment: First of all, get rid of that try/catch block! All it does is prevent you from finding out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the problem. The problem was with following tag in web.config file. However, I do not know why GoDaddy does not accept it. Nevertheless, it works now!

```
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/font-sfnt" />
</staticContent>
```

Comment: It could be that mimeMap already exists in the applicationHost.config file of the server. You should first remove it with <remove fileExtension=".otf" /> before adding it.